# como mostrar datos en index.aspx si los tengo desde el archivo index.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, db2

estoy tratando de mostrar los registros de una tabla que tengo el problema es que no los muestra  me marca el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pasa es que son mas de 3 registros en mi tabla de db2
los estoy llamando en el aspx.cs de la siguiente forma

```
conn = new Conectart();

            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conn.ConnectionString);
            OdbcCommand DbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();        



            DbCommand.CommandText = "select * from MAGICADM.ERRORCORREO ";

            List<varicorr> lsvaricorr = new List<varicorr>();
            
            

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (DbReader.Read())
                {
                    lsvaricorr.Add(new varicorr
                    {
                        asunto = DbReader["asunto"].ToString(),
                        detalleExcp = DbReader["asunto"].ToString(),
                        created_at_date = DbReader["created_at_date"].ToString(),
                        created_at_hour = DbReader["created_at_hour"].ToString()

                    });


                }

                //detalleExcps.Text = detalleExcp;
                //created_at_hours.Text = created_at_hour;
                //created_at_dates.Text = created_at_date;

                DbReader.Close();
                DbCommand.Dispose();
                connection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             
            }

        }
    }

    public class varicorr
    {
        public string created_at_date { get; set; }
        public string created_at_hour { get; set; }
        public string detalleExcp { get; set; }
        public string asunto { get; set; }
    }
```

quiero poder mostrarlo en alguna tabla desde asp
para que me la muestre con todos los registros que existan
desde uno hasta mas de dos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pones un Repeater

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repetidor" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <tr>
         <td>header 1</td>
         <td>header 2</td>
         <td>header 3</td>
         <td>header 4</td>
       </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
     <td><%#Eval("asunto") %></td>
     <td><%#Eval("detalleExcp") %></td>
     <td><%#Eval("created_at_date") %></td>
     <td><%#Eval("created_at_hour") %></td>
   </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Y en el Code Behind

```
//TODO EL CÓDIGO ANTERIOR
DbReader.Close();
DbCommand.Dispose();
connection.Close();

Repetidor.DataSource = lsvaricorr;
Repetidor.DataBind();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, jejje me tarde por quedarme pensando cual es el codebehin ya que pense estaba en la etiquete inerenths , pero los puse en el aspx.cs